# Changing the path for the logs of electron-log (within an Angular with electron app)

Tags: angular, logging, path, electron

I'm working on an Angular 6 (with electron) app.
I've successfully integrated with the electron-log library, using ngx-electron.
Now, everything works well and I get my logs into the default path of the library:
C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\[process-name]\logs

I want to change this default path, for example, to a file named main.log, located directly on the desktop.

I've tried using the following code (TypeScript):

```
public ngOnInit() {
   this.logger = this.electronService.remote.require('electron-log');
   const {app} = this.electronService.remote.require('electron');
   this.logger.transports.file.resolvePath = () => app.getPath('desktop') + '\\main.log';
   this.logger.transports.file.resolvePath();
   this.logger.info('*** app has started! ***');
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. What am I missing?
Thank You!

(When I add only the following lines of code to ngOnInit:

```
  public ngOnInit() {
   this.logger = this.electronService.remote.require('electron-log');
   this.logger.info('*** app has started! ***');
}
```

It successfully writes to the default path for the logs, mentioned above.)

Comment: I've got similar issue, no idea how to change it. What I usually get is default path concatenated with my desire path into one.

Answer (score 0):

Using electron-log through remote module is not a god idea, since:

- The remote module is deprecated
- It's pretty slow
- Overriding a function like `resolvePath` may not work in some cases

So, it's better to require and configure electron-log in the renderer process directly instead

Answer (score 0):

this.logger.transports.file.resolvePath = () => require('path).join('C:/appName/', logFolderName, logFileName);

This should work.